# python *args and lists

Tags: python, list, function, return, args

I have this assignment:

> Define a function that takes in an arbitrary number of arguments, and returns a list containing only those arguments that are even. Don't run the function simply provide the definition.

What I've tried:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return list(args%2==0)
```

Comment: What is *your* question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as follows:

```
def a (*args):
  l = []
  for i in args:
    if i%2 == 0:
      l.append(i)
  return l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def myfunc(*args):
     a=[]
     for num in args:
         if (num%2 == 0):
             a.append(num)
     return a `
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work.

```
def a (*args):
  l = []
  for i in args:
    if i%2 == 0:
      l += [i]
  return l
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is requires to be as arguments like in `range()`, iba4read's post shuld work just fine. Just in case i'll give you an examplie with a `list`, note that a ´tuple´ not alwais works as a `list`.

```
import random

array = []
for r in range(random.randint(2, 10)):
    array.append(r)


def even_numbers_of(array):
    new_array = []
    for i in array:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_array.append(i)
    return new_array


print(even_numbers_of(array))
```